Mapping the result of a selector with another selector?
I am trying to merge the data from two websockets that are being saved into two adapters. The problem is I need to sum this aggregated data and have an output array that updates when updated from the two parent sockets.
The Problem, is this selector possible?
export const selectLiveBalances = (state: RootState): LiveBalanceValue[] => {
  const balances = selectBalanceCurrencies(state) // enumArray[] 
  return balances.map((code) => selectLiveBalanceByCode(state, code)) // selectLiveBalanceByCode working as intended
}

selectBalanceCurrencies is a memoized selector from an adapter its a renamed selectIds and selectLiveBalances is a reselect createCachedSelector that caches the result of two adapters selectById selectById
I then have third selector that takes selectLiveBalances and sums the live balance data.
I have tried just only using the selectByCode but their are requirements set that need the total and partial totals of the selectLiveBalances array
My reading
Reselect - selector that invokes another selector? - I couldnt parse a solution to my problem from this
https://github.com/taskworld/rereselect - This would work but its not maintained
https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect/issues/360 - This is the same issue I am trying to solve
Some kind of solution to aggregating selectors together

selectLiveBalances, as a selector function, seems to make sense to me. What exactly is the issue or problem here? Can you [edit] to clarify the question/problem and to include a more complete [mcve] that includes how the selectors you want to use are defined?

I want selectLiveBalances to update with a dep array of [selectBalanceCurrencies, selectLiveBalanceByCode(code1), selectLiveBalanceByCode(code2)... ect] What I belive currently is happening is the selector updates on every root state change

Yeah, I got that much already. Selector functions don't use dependency arrays though. What isn't working as you are expecting? What do these selector functions do that you are trying to map the results of? See [mcve].

Ok more investigation something like this works as intended
export const selectLiveBalances = createSelector(
  [(state: RootState) => selectLiveBalanceByCode(state, CurrencyCode.BTC), (state: RootState) => selectLiveBalanceByCode(state, CurrencyCode.EUR)],
  (...data) => {
    return data
  },
)

While the above doesnt. I cant easily reproduce and example for you but I am trying to make a version of the above selector with customisable inputs from another selector like main example

By work I mean every the main example fires every time state changes while the above example only fires when the selectLiveBalanceByCode cache is invalidated. I would like to get the main one to listern for when any of the selectLiveBalanceByCode caches are invalidate and invalidate its own cache.

Here is a github issue where annoyingly the solution is fairly vague. https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect/issues/360

The main issue with your current selector function implementation is that it seems at least part of it is dynamic and depends on the results of the first selectBalanceCurrencies selector output. As far as I'm aware of you can't write a single selector function with dynamic inputs.
What you might be able to do is create a "utility" selector function that takes the current balances state and outputs the current value of each in state by balance code, and then later this array/object can be uses as input into another selector that can use the currency/balances keys returned by selectBalanceCurrencies and aggregate/map a computed value.
An example implementation might look something like the following:
// Selects the current balances state
export const selectBalances = (state: RootState): LiveBalanceValue[] => {
  return state.balances;
};

// Recomputes a map/lookup object when selectBalances updates
export const selectBalancesByCodes = createSelector(
  [selectBalances],
  (balances) => balances.reduce((balancesByCode, balance) => ({
    ...balancesByCode,
    [balance.code]: balance
  }), {}),
);

// Recomputes array of live balances when either of selectBalanceCurrencies
// or selectBalancesByCodes selectors update
export const selectLiveBalances = createSelector(
  [
    selectBalanceCurrencies,
    selectBalancesByCodes,
  ],
  (balanceCurrencies, balancesByCodes) => {
    return balanceCurrencies.map((code) => balancesByCodes[code]);
  },
);

